# Django Rest Framework: Disable save in update

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It is my first question here, after reading the similar questions I did not find what I need, thanks for your help.

I am creating a fairly simple API but I want to use best practices at the security level.

Requirement: There is a table in SQL Server with +5 million records that I should ONLY allow READ (all fields) and UPDATE (one field). This is so that a data scientist consumes data from this table and through a predictive model (I think) can assign a value to each record.

For this I mainly need 2 things:

1. That only one field is updated despite sending all the fields of the table in the Json (I think I have achieved it with my serializer).
2. And, where I have problems, **is in disabling the creation of new records when updating one that does not exist.**

I am using an UpdateAPIView to allow trying to allow a bulk update using a json like this (subrrogate_key is in my table and I use lookup_field to:

```
[
    {
        "subrrogate_key": "A1",
        "class": "A"
    },
   {
        "subrrogate_key": "A2",
        "class": "B"
    },
   {
        "subrrogate_key": "A3",
        "class": "C"
    },
]
```

When using the partial_update methods use update and this perform_update and this finally calls save and the default operation is to insert a new record if the primary key (or the one specified in lookup_field) is not found.

If I overwrite them, how can I make a new record not be inserted, and only update the field if it exists?

I tried:

Model.objects.filter (subrrogate_key = ['subrrogate_key']). Update (class = ['class])

Model.objects.update_or_create (...)

They work fine if all the keys in the Json exist, because if a new one comes they will insert (I don't want this).

P.S. I use a translator, sorry.

Comment: The `filter().update()` did not work?

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: bdbd I will update with my view, but filter().update() insert new record if don't find the pk/key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`perform_update` will create a new record if you passed a serializer that doesn't have an instance. Depending on how you wrote your view, you can simply check if there is an instance in the serializer before calling `save` in `perform_update` to prevent creating a new record:

```
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        if not serializer.instance:
            return
        serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Django implements that feature through the use of either `force_update` or `update_fields` during `save()`.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

> In some rare circumstances, it’s necessary to be able to force the
> save() method to perform an SQL INSERT and not fall back to doing an
> UPDATE. Or vice-versa: update, if possible, but not insert a new row.
> In these cases you can pass the force_insert=True or force_update=True
> parameters to the save() method.

```
model_obj.save(force_update=True)
```

or

```
model_obj.save(update_fields=['field1', 'field2'])
```